# Content Builder "Shared-Tab" not visible in child BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, sharing, content-builder

In the parent Business Unit, a folder in Content Builder is shared with a couple of child BUs. As far as I can see this, everything has been set up according to the documentation. However, in the Child-BUs the "Shared-Tab" isn't visible in the Content Builder interface.

The user I've tested this with has full administrator rights (Administrator and Marketing Cloud Administrator roles). Furthermore, I checked if any individual permissions have been set or anything else that could lead to not having the correct permissions. Everything seems right tough.

This is how the sharing looks like in the parent BU:
[image: Sharing Settings in the parent BU]

This is what I'm supposed to see in the child BU, but am only able to see in the parent BU currently:
[image: Desired view in child BU]

(Source of images: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iV6zQAE; it looks the same in my instance, but I didn't want to disclose production information)

Comment: I had exactly this behaviour: I needed to contact salesforce support and they had to change something. At first I couldn't even see shared tabs even though i shared data and stuff. It clearly is something which is not implemented perfectly

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll try that and give feedback if it was the same problem.

Comment: Aaah, just stumbled upon the same thing today with a new instance.. will open a support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

This is looking like a business rule was not turned on properly in your account. Just contact support and they will fix it.

I would advise you to look for differences between the parent BU and the child-BUs because the sharing issue is likely to not be the only problem. In one of my accounts, I had to create almost 30 cases with support to fix all the issues linked to the account not being provided correctly by SF.